# How do i execute an enumerate?

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python and am trying to do an enumerate as per below. However, I am getting an error

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

My csv file is just a single column with column header "Headlines" and I wish for this column data to be processed by textblob. Pls help me.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
from textblob import TextBlob 
import datetime 
from datetime import time 
import warnings 
import csv 

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Test.csv') 

for idx, Headlines in enumerate(df['Headlines'].values): #for each row in our df dataframe 
    newsText = df['Headlines'] 
    if Headlines: 
        soup = BeautifulSoup(newsText,"lxml") 
        sentA = TextBlob(soup.get_text())
```

My dataframe sample:

```
Headlines <br/>
-- ECONOMICS BRIEF: S&P Global Earlier Expected Fed to Raise Rates Two Times in 2017, with First One Coming in June; Follows This Week's FOMC Minutes<br/>
$50, note of choice for criminals: RBA<br/>
$A falls after RBA rates decision<br/>
$A falls on RBA's house market warning<br/>
$A falls on RBA's house market warning<br/>
$A higher after Fed minutes<br/>
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 20, in <module>
  File "C:\PycharmProjects\____\venv\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 225, in __init__
    markup, from_encoding, exclude_encodings=exclude_encodings)): 
  File "C:\PycharmProjects\____\venv\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder\_lxml.py", line 117, in prepare_markup
    markup, try_encodings, is_html, exclude_encodings)
  File "C:\PycharmProjects\_____\venv\lib\site-packages\bs4\dammit.py", line 228, in __init__
    self.markup, self.sniffed_encoding = self.strip_byte_order_mark(markup)
  File "C:\PycharmProjects\____\venv\lib\site-packages\bs4\dammit.py", line 280, in strip_byte_order_mark
    if (len(data) >= 4) and (data[:2] == b'\xfe\xff') \
  File "C:\PycharmProjects\_____\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1573, in __nonzero__
    .format(self.__class__.__name__))
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: I attempted formatting your code, please check that the indentation is correct

Comment: How did you know enumerate is causing error?

Comment: I expect the error is the `if Headlines:`, not the enumerate.  The error traceback message should give you the exact line that caused the error; it would have been more helpful to post the entire message.

Comment: Can you post a small sample of your dataframe?

Comment: Please post the entire Traceback

Comment: [Using If/Truth Statements with pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#using-if-truth-statements-with-pandas)

Comment: I am so glad that there is a strong community who replies so fast! Hi chrisz, my dataframe added above. Hi wwii, my traceback added above. I am actually unsure where the error is.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with `enumerate`. It has everything to do with the type of `Headlines` inside the loop and whether it can be converted to a boolean.

Comment: I am running into the same issue. @Alphaforte did you find a solution?